# Images are not displayed in a Laravel application in production

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, image, laravel-blade

I deployed a Laravel Application with Laravel Forge and works fine except when I upload images to show in the application.
I use this code to create a new record in a table. This new record have an "image" field where the URL of the image is stored. And the image should be stored in the "categories" folder.

```
$categoryword = Category::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'slug' => $request->slug,
                'image' => Storage::put('categories', $request->file('image')),
                'description' => $request->description,
                'body' => $request->body,
                'example' => $request->example,
                'exception' => $request->exception,
                'type' => "Ortographic Rules",
                'clasification' => "Words",
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
            ]);
```

Also, this is the code to show the image in a blade view:

```
<img id="image" name="image" src="{{ asset("storage/$categoryword->image")}}" alt="" height="400px" width="700px"/>
```

Locally, it works properly and images can be viewed. But when I try to upload a new record with an Image in production server with Laravel Forge I have this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

In the production server I use:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

But when I enter to the public folder and enter to "storage" folder, that folder is empty.

But if I go to the "storage" folder which is in the same level of "public" folder inside my production server and I enter to that folder I have this three files:

```
app                  framework           logs
```

And inside of "app" folder I have this two files:

```
public                 categories
```

So, "categories" folder where the images I upload are stored is in this location but I cannot show the images that I upload.
How can I fix that and make the "storage" folder of "public" folder contains this "categories" folder?
Sorry for my English

Comment: the symlink that is created by the `storage:link` command (by default) is `public/storage -> storage/app/public` ... did you change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem was in the filesystems disk, so go to .env and change `FILESYSTEM_DISK=local` to `FILESYSTEM_DISK=public`.
Don't forget to add the name of disk like that

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('categories', $request->file('image'));
```